# Proving a group variety is quasicompact (or providing a counterexample)

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

I would like to prove or provide a counterexample to the following statement:
Every group variety (i.e. an algebraic variety $X$ with a morphism $m:X\times X\to X$, $i:X\to X$, and an element $e\in X$, such that $m(m(x,y),z) = m(x,m(y,z))$, $m(i(x),x) = e$, and $m(e,x) = m(x,e)=x$ hold for all $x,y,z \in X$) is quasi-compact.

At first I thought this statement should be false, since we don't know anything about the variety except the fact that it has a group structure (which is of course very strong). But then I figured that every variety which can be covered by finitely many affine patches, is quasi-compact. So to look for a counterexample, I would have to look for a variety which consists of an infinite amount of affine pieces AND carries a group structure. I did not succeed in this.

So my thoughts were the following:

Either a group variety can be covered by finitely many affine patches (using the fact that for every subvariety $U\subset X$, $gU \cong U$ as varieties for all $g\in X$), or we might use the multiplication on an open cover. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What does 'variety' mean? I think for a lot of people this means finite type over $\text{Spec}(k)$ which implies quasi-compact. Otherwise you can look at something like the constant group scheme $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ which is represented by an infinite disjoint union of $\text{Spec}(k)$.

Comment: A $k $-space which is locally isomorphic to an affine variety, which is a closed set in $\mathbb {A}^n $. We haven't seen schemes or spectra in our course, so I doubt this is the answer they want.

Comment: Well, any closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ is quasi-compact.

Comment: Do you at least know about Noetherian rings?

Comment: Dear Moise ,  how  does this(Noetherian rings) help?